# originX and originY are not set to center by default in 1.3.9

Tags: fabricjs

I only would like to inform you that you forgot to set originX and originY to center. I copied the latest version and noticed that all my objects are moved. I set the origin to center and then everything looks like before. In the doc default value is also center.

Answer (score 6):

This was a latest change :

Please check this:
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/330784ac2c7297cd34c2c7fbe6ea69c8079b9e85#commitcomment-4529854

You can still keep things the same in your app by simply doing something like

```
fabric.Object.prototype.originX = fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center'
```

Comment: thx for this, was looking for a global way to set it back to center/center