# Positioning a polygon by its origin (fabric.js)

Tags: fabricjs

I have created a simple hexagon by defining the points symmetrically about an origin. However, the hexagon is not being positioned relative to its 0,0 point on the canvas. It seems to be using the top/left of the bounding rectangle. Is there a way to use the 0,0 point as its origin?

```
var HH = 87;
var HV = 50;

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
    backgroundColor: '#e0e0e0'
});

hex = new fabric.Polygon([
        {x: 0, y: -2 * HV},
        {x: HH, y: -HV},
        {x: HH, y: HV},
        {x: 0, y: 2 * HV},
        {x: -HH, y: HV},
        {x: -HH, y: -HV}
    ], {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        fill: 'blue',
        selectable: true
    });

canvas.add(hex);
```

I draw this polygon about an arbitrary origin. When I place it at X,Y on the canvas, I want the 0,0 point of the polygon to rest on the canvas point X,Y.

[image]

Comment: which plot tool package you are using?

Comment: If I set originX and originY on the polygon to 0, it works as I want, but the docs say those properties take 'left', 'center', 'right'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `originX` and `originY` as you pointed out in your comments. The value you want is `center`

```
hex = new fabric.Polygon([
        { x: 0, y: -2 * HV },
        { x: HH, y: -HV },
        { x: HH, y: HV },
        { x: 0, y: 2 * HV },
        { x: -HH, y: HV },
        { x: -HH, y: -HV }
], {
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    fill: 'blue',
    selectable: true
});
```

Note that you don't need the top and left values (they default to 0).

---

> If I set originX and originY on the polygon to 0, it works as I want,
>   but the docs say those properties take 'left', 'center', 'right'.

This is because the bit of code that translates points does something like

```
point coordinates = intial value

if (originX === 'left') {
    adjust point x value
}
else if (originX === 'right') {
    adjust point y value
}

// do similar thing for originY
...
```

So any value that is not 'left' or 'right' will be treated as 'center'. You can test this by doing something like

```
hex = new fabric.Polygon([
        { x: 0, y: -2 * HV },
        { x: HH, y: -HV },
        { x: HH, y: HV },
        { x: 0, y: 2 * HV },
        { x: -HH, y: HV },
        { x: -HH, y: -HV }
], {
    originX: 'something',
    originY: 'something',
    fill: 'blue',
    selectable: true
});
```

though I wouldn't rely on it functioning similarly when the library is updated.

Comment: Thanks. That makes fabric.js not a s useful as I would like. When I define a shape by its origin, I want to position it by its origin, but by its edges or center. Are there better libraries that have more sensible options?

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823024/originx-and-originy-are-not-set-to-center-by-default-in-1-3-9. Cheers!

Comment: This isn't useful to me. I also checked out paper.js. It also does not do origin properly. I have a hard time believing that two pretty complex drawing libraries miss something so fundamental.